# Is there a Find & Replace function in ReSharper?

Tags: resharper, replace

I've just implemented a custom MessageBox for my application. I'd now like to replace any calls to MessageBox.Show() with my custom implementation, which is MsgBox.Show()**. I realise I could do this with a simple global Find & Replace but I'm wondering if there's a safer/better way to do it with ReSharper?

**all the parameters being passed in are the same in both cases.

Answer (score 8):

There is a tool called `Structural search and replace` in ReSharper. It is definitely safer to use than a simple Find & Replace, but it is a little bit more complex. I've tried to make an instruction for you, but I didn't test it. Try it on your own risk. Search Google for `ReSharper structural search and replace` to find more info.

1. Go to `ReSharper | Find | Search with pattern`.
2. Type `$t$.Show($args$)` in the text field.
3. Click `Add Placeholder -> Expression`. Type `t` for name, then type `MessageBox` for expression type and choose the correct type from suggestion list.
4. Click `Add Placeholder -> Argument`. Type `args` for name, leave other fields with default values.
5. Ensure that this pattern finds your target calls by clicking `Find`.
6. Now go back to `ReSharper | Find | Search with pattern` (your pattern should be still there).
7. Click `Replace`.
8. Type `MsgBox.Show($args$)`.
9. Click `Replace`.
10. Now correct usings where necessary. Unfortunately, this only can be done semi-automatically, by finding errors via ReSharper's solution-wide analysis or by compiling your project and then clicking Alt-Enter on any error to invoke ReSharper's fix for adding usings.

Comment: unfortunately I've already done it the old-fashioned way, so I can't really test this either. If someone wants to test this and it works, please update here and I'll award the correct answer.

Comment: This tool is really buggy when it comes to type matches. It silently drops things like `static` or `readonly`. It doesn't really support generics. I really don't recommend it.